# Zend multiple forms

Tags: forms, zend-framework, validation

In some page I have 2 forms, I need some solution to define which form was submited. I cant't check with `isValid();` because form are placed in one page and form which is not submited will show validating errors.

Best sulution will be define by form name and after check validation, it's possible to define which one form is submited without validating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the name of the two submit button and validate the form which was submitted

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="form1" value="Submit Form1">
</form>

<form>
    <input type="submit" name="form2" value="Submit Form2">
</form>
```

In the controller

```
if(isset($_POST ["form1"]))
{
    //validate form 1
}
else if(isset($_POST ["form2"]))
{
    //validate form 3
}
```